# PrimeFaces UI SelectOneButton

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 4.0 with JSF 2.0

my requirement is to do some specific task behind  (ON / OFF) selection button, my code is like

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid>
        <p:selectOneButton value="#{buttonBean.number}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ON" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="OFF" itemValue="0" />
        </p:selectOneButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

for now UI and all is fine but, value is not passed on click to the bean which is `buttonBean.number` unless i submit it using a submit button.

My aim is to pass and set `number = 0` and `number = 1` by only click not submit it, where "0" is for Off and "1" is for On,

Comment: Why not use selectBooleanCheckBox for this? Please refer http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectBooleanCheckbox.jsf

Comment: Approved UI is like this. having large button ON/OFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution without submit

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="listFilter" value="#{sess.selectedFileId}">
    <p:ajax update="mytable" listener="#{beanBacking.fileChanged()}" partialSubmit="true" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- ALL --" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{beanBacking.fileList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

`<p:ajax />` learn p:ajax more [HERE](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/ajax.html), from this page will not even refersh.